# How to set up a developer security certificate in under 5 minutes

Tags: windows, apache, ssl-certificate

I've just spent 2 days unsuccessfully setting up a security certificate for Apache on Windows. I tried:

- Let's Encrypt (doesn't work with local domains)
- A self-signed certificate (most instructions are for Apache on Linux, or IIS on Windows)

I finally managed to create a self-signed certificate using the Windows version of OpenSSL:

> ```
> C:\Server\Apache24\conf>openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout projectsplat.dev.key -out projectsplat.dev.crt -days 1000 -nodes
> Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
> ................................................+++++
> ...................+++++
> writing new private key to 'projectsplat.dev.key'
> -----
> You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
> into your certificate request.
> What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
> There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
> For some fields there will be a default value,
> If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
> -----
> Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:
> State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:
> Locality Name (eg, city) []:
> Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:
> Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:
> Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:
> Email Address []:
> ```

I'm a bit confused because it never asked for the domain name, but it installed successfully in Apache without complaining. However, when I open the URL on my browser, I get a message:

> ### Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from projectsplat.dev (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
>   NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
>   projectsplat.dev normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Vivaldi tried to connect to projectsplat.dev this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be projectsplat.dev, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because Vivaldi stopped the connection before any data was exchanged.
>
> You cannot visit projectsplat.dev right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.

I found instructions for installing the self-signed certificate in Chrome/Opera/Vivaldi and followed them, getting a "Successfully installed" message at the end. Great! So I refreshed the page and got exactly the same message as above.

I looked up HSTS but I didn't see any information about resolving this error.

How can you create an SSL certificate in under 5 minutes that just works?

Comment: It looks like Google has broken all `.dev` TLDs: https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/

Answer (score 0):

Open port 80 & 443 to the internet, run LetsEncrypt, then close the ports.

It shouldn't be a big risk letting a new, fully patched version of IIS talk to the internet unless you have private stuff there.

You'll need to do it again in 90 days.

Comment: How is that going to work without IIS? I'm using Apache.

Comment: Sorry, I misread it. It's the same thing for Apache or whatever else you're running. 

Open the ports, and run the LetsEncrypt version for your OS.

Comment: You're saying to reconfigure the work network to allow internet access to my work computer?

Comment: I have no idea where you are, but yes, your machine needs to talk to the internet for letsencrypt to work. The only other option is self-signed (which you just found out isn't very useful). Nobody is going to issue you a cert without validating that it's reachable. If this is strictly internal you can setup your own CA and create whatever certs you want, although you'll need to install the CA root cert in your browsers.

Comment: That conversation would either be an immediate "No" or take longer than 5 minutes. My machine can talk to Let's Encrypt. The error message I'm getting is that my local domain name is not registered anywhere.

Comment: Then you're left with setting up your own local CA or not using https. There are no quick fixes anymore. Browsers used to be much more liberal about what certs they accepted and CAs were much more liberal about certs they issue, but neither of those are true anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178166/discussion-between-cj-dennis-and-terry-carmen).